# How do I enable the create consumer group button for event hubs in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I cannot create Consumer Groups for any event hub I create.  The "+" button is always disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a basic event hub the number of consumer groups is limited to 1. Standard gives you 20. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/

Go to Settings -> Scale to change the message tier from basic to standard.

Comment: That's exactly what it was - thanks!  The $Default group counts as 1, of course.